# Django signals for different apps

Tags: django, django-signals

I need to have separate signals for each app of my project. But after saving a model in one of the apps signals trigger from all apps, so I have duplicated messages from my signals. What is the right way to set up signals for different apps of Django project?

signals.py of my app1:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import *


@receiver(post_save)
def log_app1_updated_added_event(sender, **kwargs):
    '''Writes information about newly added or updated objects of app1 into log file'''

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    app1_object = kwargs['instance']
    
    if kwargs['created']:
        logger.info(f'added {app1_object }')
    else:
        logger.info(f'updated {app1_object }')
```

signals.py of my app2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import *


@receiver(post_save)
def log_app2_updated_added_event(sender, **kwargs):
    '''Writes information about newly added or updated objects of app2 into log file'''

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    app2_object = kwargs['instance']
    
    if kwargs['created']:
        logger.info(f'added {app2_object }')
    else:
        logger.info(f'updated {app2_object }')
```

apps.py of my app1:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'App1'

    def ready(self):
        from app1 import signals
```

apps.py of my app2:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'App2'

    def ready(self):
        from app2 import signals
```

and here is section of loggers in my project settings.py

```
'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console',],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'app1.signals': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'app2.signals': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
     }
```

Comment: So you only want to receive signals for saving objects of modules defined in that specific app?

Comment: I want different signals process saving objects for only their app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that makes perfect sense: apps are not that much functionally isolated, it just makes it easy to export models and logic in a separate app, then plug these into another project, and thus makes code more *reusable*.

But if you make a signal that listens to `post_save` signals, it will be triggered when saving models of *any* app. The signal handler does not limit listening to models of its own app. That would also limit the signals too much: it would for example make it impossible to listen to changes by the `User` model, since that is defined in the `django.contrib.auth` app.

But we can filter it to only let signals process only the model objects of their own app with:

```
@receiver(post_save)
def log_app1_updated_added_event(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    'Writes information about newly added or updated objects of app1 into log file'
    if sender._meta.app_label == 'app1':
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        app1_object = instance

        if kwargs['created']:
            logger.info(f'added {app1_object }')
        else:
            logger.info(f'updated {app1_object }')
```

we thus check if the model has an `app_label` that is `'app1'` and if not, we just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks it is the solution for my task